# Почему переменная "k" не принимает новые значения? Почему со второго цикла переменная становится постоянной?

Tags: python, while, variable

Задача: Получить список, в моём случае [5,3,2,2].
Проблема: Проблема с переменной k, которая после второго цикла становится постоянной.
Вопросы: Можно ли исправить положение переменной k так чтобы я получил вышеизложенный список?
Пожелание: Какую информацию почитать чтобы такой ошибки больше не было?
Исходный код:

```
a = [2,3,5,7]
c = []
n = 50
while len(a) != 0:
    b = a[0]
    k = 0
    while b <= n:
        k = k + 1
        n = n // b
    print(k)
    del a[0]
    c.append(k)
    print("")
print(c)
```

Если код фигня, то предложите свой более правильный.
Заранее Благодарю !

Comment: как вообще звучит задача? Нельзя исправить код, если неизвестно, что он должен делать.

Comment: Господа, я здесь впервые , поэтому мой вопрос может быть, некорректным надеюсь на ваше понимание. Я попробую сформулировать задачу более точно :
Имеется список a,и имеются число n, необходимо определить Список c. Элементы которого будут являться  максимальным показателем степени элементов списка, т.е степень которого не превышает число n. 
```Задача 
n = 50 
a = [2,3,5,7] 
c = ? 
res = a**C
условие чтобы каждый элемент res был максимален и меньше числа n
Решение 
n = 50
a = [2,3,5,7] 
c = [5,3,2,2] 
a**c = 2**5 = 32...
res = [32,27,25,49] Каждый элемент максимален и меньше 50.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка не в `k` ошибка в `n`. Т.к после первого выполнения второго `while` `n = 1`, и так до окончания всех циклов, необходимо былло ввести дополнительную переменную.
Я ввел новую переменную `z`  и у меня всё получилось.
Вот правильный код:

```
a = [2,3,5,7]
c = []
n = 50
while len(a) != 0:
    b = a[0]
    k = 0
    z = n
    while b <= z:
        k = k + 1
        z = z // b
    del a[0]
    c.append(k)
print(c)
```

Таким образом посмотрел на код со стороны и нашел проблему)

Comment: сделайте хотя бы `for b in a:`, убрав удаление из списка

Comment: Я был бы вам благодарен, если вы бы посоветовали каким образом можно понять цикл `for` .Для меня из всех циклов этот является самым непонятным, я его стараюсь избегать. Ну или хотя бы пришлите свой код более автоматизированный и краткий с циклом `for` , я попытаюсь его понять.

Comment: @Iluhensun вы бы для начала саму задачу описали, чтобы вам можно было дать адекватный ответ. Что значит `Получить список, в моём случае [5,3,2,2]`, почему именно он?

Comment: То, что я написал - простейшая форма for - "обойти все элементы списка", если убрать del, то всё будет, как нужно

Comment: @Iluhensun 1. вообще-то, цикл `for` по списку и другим итерируемым объектам с самого начала был крутой фишкой питона (потом уже С++ и прочие подтянулись), так что изучите и пользуйтесь!  2. `b = a[0] и del a[0]` заменяется командой `b = a.pop(0)`. 3. `while len(a) != 0:` прсто заменяете на `while a:`